# How to recover texture paths when opening autosaved files?

Tags: blend-files, path

As Blender kept crashing on a project, I had to restart from autosaved files several times, a real hassle. Frankly I don't understand how they are supposed to work with attached textures. My preferences are:

- File Paths | Data | Temporary files: Not set
- File Paths | Data | Textures path: `//`
- Save & Load | Blend Files | Default to: `Relative paths`

Autosaved files are stored in my case in `[user]\AppData\Local\Temp`. I first move this file to the original folder in order to allow relative paths to work, then open it. The World HDRI image should be found but Blender makes everything pink and logs:

```
Read blend: [user]\Desktop\Blender Projects\Blender Day 3_autosaved_copy.blend
GPUTexture: Blender Texture Not Loaded!
```

Output of `File | External Data | Report Missing Files`:

```
Warning: Path '[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\Textures\HDRI\hamburg_hbf_2k.hdr' not found
```

The original HDRI path is:

```
[user]\Desktop\Blender Projects\Textures\HDRI\hamburg_hbf_2k.hdr
```

But by some mysterious mechanism, it was changed to:

```
[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\Textures\HDRI\hamburg_hbf_2k.hdr
```

My question are:

- How to prevent such unexpected redirection
- How to fix a corrupted file in a single step, regardless of the number of resources affected by this redirection?

---

To reproduce this case: Set an HDRI image for World material, wait the necessary time for Autosave to be triggered (varies according to preferences), reload the autosaved file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't open these files using open dialog or directly from file browser, use a special tool in blender for recovering files:

- Open up Blender
- Go to **File** → **Recover** → **Auto save...** and open the file here. This will open the recovered file, keeping all links alive.

Then the file is loaded, and it seems everything is ok, and you see *(Recovered)* in the title bar, save file:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> this will save file to original location, and *(Recovered)* indicator will be removed

Comment: Double check. I haven't faced problem with that either on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Loading the [recovered file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP9UL.png), same pink color and same missing path `Warning: Path 'C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Temp\Textures\HDRI\hamburg_hbf_2k.hdr' not found`

Comment: Maybe this recover is from an already broken file... Try different one.

Comment: With a fresh file it works. What I see is the path in the Windows title bar is set to the original folder, while when not working it is set to the temporary folder. Strange.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have already mess up these files, so some mistakes may happen... But if you get used to my suggestion, it will work every time in the future.

Comment: You must be right. Probably I opened the file from the temp folder (hence breaking relative paths), then it was autosaved under the same name, then I opened this last file with Recover Auto Save.